# CommandBarButton Icon getting black background

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am trying to make an outlook 2007 addIn. While setting an icon to the CommandBarButton the icon's background is turning black.

[image: Black background commandBarButtton]

The code I am using is:

```
private CommandBar _menuBar;

private void AddScheduleMeetingButton()
{
    var scheduleButton = (CommandBarButton)_menuBar
                .Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, 1, true);

    scheduleButton.BeginGroup = true;
    scheduleButton.Caption = ScheduleButtonCaption;
    scheduleButton.Picture = GetImage(Resources.schedule_meeting16);
    scheduleButton.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption;
    scheduleButton.Click += UnirowScheduleButtonClick;
    scheduleButton.Visible = true;
}
```

GetImage() function using the AxHost approach given by Microsoft:

```
private IPictureDisp GetImage(Icon newIcon)
{
    IPictureDisp tempImage = null;
    try
    {
        var newImageList = new ImageList();
        newImageList.Images.Add(newIcon);

        tempImage = MyHost.GetIPictureDispFromPicture(newImageList.Images[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return tempImage;
}
```

What is the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

There is a special workaround to support custom icon transparency with `CommandBarButton` within Office. See [MS KB288771](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288771) for information on **How To Create a Transparent Picture For Office CommandBar Buttons** leveraging the Win32 API.

#### Copying a Transparent Office Toolbar Picture

1. Use Microsoft Paint (*or a third-party image editor*) to create a 256-color bitmap with a design of your choice. The image should be no bigger than 16 pixels wide and 16 pixels high.
2. Fill in all areas of the bitmap you want to be transparent with the color magenta (RGB(255, 0, 255)), and then save the bitmap as `C:\MyTestPic.bmp`.
3. Start Visual Basic and create a new Standard project. Form1 is created by default.
4. Add a button to Form1, and then add the following code to the button's `Click` event:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim oPic As StdPicture
   Dim oWord As Object
   Dim oCommandBar As Object
   Dim oButton As Object
   
 ' Load the picture (.bmp file) to use for the button image.
   Set oPic = LoadPicture("C:\MyTestPic.bmp")
   
 ' Start Microsoft Word for Automation and create a new
 ' toolbar and button to test the PasteFace method.
   Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   oWord.Visible = True
   
   Set oCommandBar = oWord.CommandBars.Add("Test Bar")
   oCommandBar.Visible = True
   
   Set oButton = oCommandBar.Controls.Add(1)
   With oButton
      .Caption = "Test Button"
      .Style = 1
      
    ' Here we create a mask based on the image and put both
    ' the image and the mask on the clipboard. Any color areas with
    ' magenta will be transparent.
      CopyBitmapAsButtonFace oPic, &HFF00FF
      
    ' PasteFace will now add the image with transparency.
      .PasteFace
      
      .Visible = True
   End With
   
   MsgBox "You have a new button with a transparent picture.", _
         vbMsgBoxSetForeground
   
   Set oButton = Nothing
   
   If MsgBox("Do you want to delete the toolbar?", _
        vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
      oCommandBar.Delete
   End If
   
   Set oCommandBar = Nothing
   Set oWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

(5).  On the Project menu, click Add Module, and paste the following code in the code window for the new module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Type BITMAPINFOHEADER '40 bytes
   biSize As Long
   biWidth As Long
   biHeight As Long
   biPlanes As Integer
   biBitCount As Integer
   biCompression As Long
   biSizeImage As Long
   biXPelsPerMeter As Long
   biYPelsPerMeter As Long
   biClrUsed As Long
   biClrImportant As Long
End Type

Public Type BITMAP
   bmType As Long
   bmWidth As Long
   bmHeight As Long
   bmWidthBytes As Long
   bmPlanes As Integer
   bmBitsPixel As Integer
   bmBits As Long
End Type

' ===================================================================
'   GDI/Drawing Functions (to build the mask)
' ===================================================================
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateBitmap Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal nPlanes As Long, _
   ByVal nBitCount As Long, lpBits As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetBkColor Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetBkColor Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal crColor As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetTextColor Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetTextColor Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal crColor As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hDestDC As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
   ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, _
   ByVal xSrc As Long, ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateHalftonePalette Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectPalette Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hPalette As Long, _
   ByVal bForceBackground As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RealizePalette Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OleTranslateColor Lib "oleaut32.dll" _
  (ByVal lOleColor As Long, ByVal lHPalette As Long, _
   lColorRef As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDIBits Lib "gdi32" _
  (ByVal aHDC As Long, ByVal hBitmap As Long, ByVal nStartScan As Long, _
   ByVal nNumScans As Long, lpBits As Any, lpBI As Any, _
   ByVal wUsage As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetObjectAPI Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetObjectA" _
  (ByVal hObject As Long, ByVal nCount As Long, lpObject As Any) As Long

' ===================================================================
'   Clipboard APIs
' ===================================================================
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function RegisterClipboardFormat Lib "user32" _
  Alias "RegisterClipboardFormatA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Const CF_DIB = 8

' ===================================================================
'   Memory APIs (for clipboard transfers)
' ===================================================================
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
  (pDest As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal cbLength As Long)
Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Const GMEM_DDESHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2

' ===================================================================
'  CopyBitmapAsButtonFace
'
'  This is the public function to call to create a mask based on the
'  bitmap provided and copy both to the clipboard. The first parameter
'  is a standard VB Picture object. The second should be the color in
'  the image you want to be made transparent.
'
'  Note: This code sample does limited error handling and is designed
'  for VB only (not VBA). You will need to make changes as appropriate
'  to modify the code to suit your needs.
'
' ===================================================================
Public Sub CopyBitmapAsButtonFace(ByVal picSource As StdPicture, _
  ByVal clrMaskColor As OLE_COLOR)
   Dim hPal As Long
   Dim hdcScreen As Long
   Dim hbmButtonFace As Long
   Dim hbmButtonMask As Long
   Dim bDeletePal As Boolean
   Dim lMaskClr As Long
   
 ' Check to make sure we have a valid picture.
   If picSource Is Nothing Then GoTo err_invalidarg
   If picSource.Type <> vbPicTypeBitmap Then GoTo err_invalidarg
   If picSource.Handle = 0 Then GoTo err_invalidarg
   
 ' Get the DC for the display device we are on.
   hdcScreen = GetDC(0)
   hPal = picSource.hPal
   If hPal = 0 Then
      hPal = CreateHalftonePalette(hdcScreen)
      bDeletePal = True
   End If
   
 ' Translate the OLE_COLOR value to a GDI COLORREF value based on the palette.
   OleTranslateColor clrMaskColor, hPal, lMaskClr
      
 ' Create a mask based on the image handed in (hbmButtonMask is the result).
   CreateButtonMask picSource.Handle, lMaskClr, hdcScreen, _
          hPal, hbmButtonMask
         
 ' Let VB copy the bitmap to the clipboard (for the CF_DIB).
   Clipboard.SetData picSource, vbCFDIB

 ' Now copy the Button Mask.
   CopyButtonMaskToClipboard hbmButtonMask, hdcScreen
   
 ' Delete the mask and clean up (a copy is on the clipboard).
   DeleteObject hbmButtonMask
   If bDeletePal Then DeleteObject hPal
   ReleaseDC 0, hdcScreen
   
Exit Sub
err_invalidarg:
   Err.Raise 481 'VB Invalid Picture Error
End Sub

' ===================================================================
'  CreateButtonMask -- Internal helper function
' ===================================================================
Private Sub CreateButtonMask(ByVal hbmSource As Long, _
  ByVal nMaskColor As Long, ByVal hdcTarget As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, _
  ByRef hbmMask As Long)
   
   Dim hdcSource As Long
   Dim hdcMask As Long
   Dim hbmSourceOld As Long
   Dim hbmMaskOld As Long
   Dim hpalSourceOld As Long
   Dim uBM As BITMAP
   
 ' Get some information about the bitmap handed to us.
   GetObjectAPI hbmSource, 24, uBM
   
 ' Check the size of the bitmap given.
   If uBM.bmWidth < 1 Or uBM.bmWidth > 30000 Then Exit Sub
   If uBM.bmHeight < 1 Or uBM.bmHeight > 30000 Then Exit Sub
 
 ' Create a compatible DC, load the palette and the bitmap.
   hdcSource = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcTarget)
   hpalSourceOld = SelectPalette(hdcSource, hPal, True)
   RealizePalette hdcSource
   hbmSourceOld = SelectObject(hdcSource, hbmSource)

 ' Create a black and white mask the same size as the image.
   hbmMask = CreateBitmap(uBM.bmWidth, uBM.bmHeight, 1, 1, ByVal 0)
   
 ' Create a compatble DC for it and load it.
   hdcMask = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcTarget)
   hbmMaskOld = SelectObject(hdcMask, hbmMask)
   
 ' All you need to do is set the mask color as the background color
 ' on the source picture, and set the forground color to white, and
 ' then a simple BitBlt will make the mask for you.
   SetBkColor hdcSource, nMaskColor
   SetTextColor hdcSource, vbWhite
   BitBlt hdcMask, 0, 0, uBM.bmWidth, uBM.bmHeight, hdcSource, _
       0, 0, vbSrcCopy
   
 ' Clean up the memory DCs.
   SelectObject hdcMask, hbmMaskOld
   DeleteDC hdcMask

   SelectObject hdcSource, hbmSourceOld
   SelectObject hdcSource, hpalSourceOld
   DeleteDC hdcSource

End Sub

' ===================================================================
'  CopyButtonMaskToClipboard -- Internal helper function
' ===================================================================
Private Sub CopyButtonMaskToClipboard(ByVal hbmMask As Long, _
  ByVal hdcTarget As Long)
   Dim cfBtnFace As Long
   Dim cfBtnMask As Long
   Dim hGMemFace As Long
   Dim hGMemMask As Long
   Dim lpData As Long
   Dim lpData2 As Long
   Dim hMemTmp As Long
   Dim cbSize As Long
   Dim arrBIHBuffer(50) As Byte
   Dim arrBMDataBuffer() As Byte
   Dim uBIH As BITMAPINFOHEADER
   uBIH.biSize = 40
   
 ' Get the BITMAPHEADERINFO for the mask.
   GetDIBits hdcTarget, hbmMask, 0, 0, ByVal 0&, uBIH, 0
   CopyMemory arrBIHBuffer(0), uBIH, 40

 ' Make sure it is a mask image.
   If uBIH.biBitCount <> 1 Then Exit Sub
   If uBIH.biSizeImage < 1 Then Exit Sub
   
 ' Create a temp buffer to hold the bitmap bits.
   ReDim Preserve arrBMDataBuffer(uBIH.biSizeImage + 4) As Byte
   
 ' Open the clipboard.
   If Not CBool(OpenClipboard(0)) Then Exit Sub
   
 ' Get the cf for button face and mask.
   cfBtnFace = RegisterClipboardFormat("Toolbar Button Face")
   cfBtnMask = RegisterClipboardFormat("Toolbar Button Mask")
     
 ' Open DIB on the clipboard and make a copy of it for the button face.
   hMemTmp = GetClipboardData(CF_DIB)
   If hMemTmp <> 0 Then
      cbSize = GlobalSize(hMemTmp)
      hGMemFace = GlobalAlloc(&H2002, cbSize)
      If hGMemFace <> 0 Then
         lpData = GlobalLock(hMemTmp)
         lpData2 = GlobalLock(hGMemFace)
         CopyMemory ByVal lpData2, ByVal lpData, cbSize
         GlobalUnlock hGMemFace
         GlobalUnlock hMemTmp
      
         If SetClipboardData(cfBtnFace, hGMemFace) = 0 Then
            GlobalFree hGMemFace
         End If
         
      End If
   End If
   
 ' Now get the mask bits and the rest of the header.
   GetDIBits hdcTarget, hbmMask, 0, uBIH.biSizeImage, _
        arrBMDataBuffer(0), arrBIHBuffer(0), 0
      
 ' Copy them to global memory and set it on the clipboard.
   hGMemMask = GlobalAlloc(&H2002, uBIH.biSizeImage + 50)
   If hGMemMask <> 0 Then
         lpData = GlobalLock(hGMemMask)
         CopyMemory ByVal lpData, arrBIHBuffer(0), 48
         CopyMemory ByVal (lpData + 48), _
                       arrBMDataBuffer(0), uBIH.biSizeImage
         GlobalUnlock hGMemMask
         
         If SetClipboardData(cfBtnMask, hGMemMask) = 0 Then
            GlobalFree hGMemMask
         End If
         
   End If
   
 ' We're done.
   CloseClipboard
   
End Sub
```

(6). Press F5 to run the Visual Basic application. Click the command button to automate Word, add a new toolbar and button, and paste the image of the bitmap with the transparency.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any idea if the code is available in C# for me to try in my project. And the supported products given in the Microsoft support page does not include Office 2007.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this much easier.
First create a class

```
public class IconConverter : System.Windows.Forms.AxHost
    {
        private IconConverter()
            : base(string.Empty)
        {
        }

        public static stdole.IPictureDisp GetIPictureDispFromImage(System.Drawing.Image image)
        {

            return (stdole.IPictureDisp)GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image);
        }
    }
```

Secondly, we need to create a mask image

```
private stdole.IPictureDisp GetPictureMask(Bitmap img) {

            if (img.IsNotNull()) {

                int rgb;
                Color c;

                for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
                    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++) {
                        c = img.GetPixel(x, y);
                        Color m = Color.Empty;

                        if (c.B == 0 && c.R == 0 && c.G == 0) {
                            m = Color.White;                            
                        }
                        else {
                            m = Color.Black;
                        }

                        img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(c.A, m.R, m.G, m.B));
                    }

                return IconConverter.GetIPictureDispFromImage(img);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

at the end of the assign icons to a button

```
commandBarButton.Picture = IconConverter.GetIPictureDispFromImage(orginalImage);
commandBarButton.Mask = GetPictureMask(orginalImage);
```